# I want to add a page favorites button with flutter that is saved even in local context

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm making a learning app. But here, I would like to bookmark only the problem I want out of hundreds of problems, so that the mark appears on the problem selection page next time.

The question is whether this can only be implemented in flutter without firebase or any other database.

Is it possible to implement it locally?

```
child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text('1-1',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 25,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),

          ),

          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline),
                iconSize: 25,
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                 //here
                }
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: yes, you can do it with the help of flutter shared preference package https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/install. Data stored in system preferences won't be cleared unless user manually set it to empty (clear it manually)  or uninstall the apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Flutter apps you have some options to store data in local storage permanently. For example, you can use one of these options:

1. **Shared preferences**
   add this package to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
```

and run `flutter pub get`. Now, You are able to use it based on this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example).

2. **SQLite**
   add this package to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
```

and run `flutter pub get`. Now, You are able to use it based on this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite/example).

**Note:** Usually, it is better to store a small amount of data using shared preferences and large data based on a database table. personally, I prefer shared preferences for your application.